# How can I elegantly handle state when parsing line oriented files using regex?

Tags: regex, perl, dynamic-programming

I have a perl script that I use to extract data from a raw data/log file. I need help on making the script dynamic. First, let me show you the part of the perl script and raw data file.

Perl script:

```
    if ( /Catalyst tester (\S+)\S+/ )
    {
        $DETAILS{tester_name} = $1;
    }
    if ( /(CATALYST_TH\s*1)/ )
    {
        $FOUND_CAT = 1;
        $DETAILS{test_head} = $1;
        $TEST_HEAD = $1;
    }

    if ($FOUND_CAT)
    {
        if ( /(BACKPLANE\s*A)/ )
        {
            $FRAME = $TEST_HEAD .' '. $1;
            $FOUND_BACKPLANE_A = 1;
        }

        if ( /(BACKPLANE\s*B)/ )
        {
            $FRAME = $TEST_HEAD . ' ' . $1;
            $FOUND_BACKPLANE_B = 1;
        }
    }

    if ( /END/ )
    {
        $FOUND_CAT = 0;
        $FOUND_BACKPLANE_A = 0;
        $FOUND_BACKPLANE_B = 0;
        $FOUND_PRECISION_1 = 0;
        $FOUND_PRECISION_2 = 0;
        $FOUND_UB_SPS = 0;
        $FOUND_HSD100_1 = 0;
        $FOUND_HSD100_2 = 0;
        $FOUND_HSD100_3 = 0;
        $FOUND_TSY = 0;
        $FOUND_TIME_SUB = 0;
    }

    if ($FOUND_BACKPLANE_A)
    {
        if ( /(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+(?:\d+\s+){2}((?!.*EMPTY\b).+)$/ )
        {
            push @{$DETAILS{frame}}, $FRAME;
            push @{$DETAILS{slot}}, $1;
            push @{$DETAILS{part_no}},  $2;
            push @{$DETAILS{serial_no}},  $3;
            push @{$DETAILS{board_name}},  $4;

        }
    }

    if ($FOUND_BACKPLANE_B)
    {
        if ( /(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+((?!.*EMPTY\b).+)$/ )
        {
            push @{$DETAILS{frame}}, $FRAME;
            push @{$DETAILS{slot}}, $1;
            push @{$DETAILS{part_no}},  $2;
            push @{$DETAILS{serial_no}},  $3;
            push @{$DETAILS{board_name}},  $4;
        }
    }

    if( /(PRECISION\_AC\s*1)/ )
    {
        $FOUND_PRECISION_1 = 1;
        $FRAME = $1;
    }

    if ($FOUND_PRECISION_1)
    {
        if ( /(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+((?!.*EMPTY\b).+)/ )
        {
            push @{$DETAILS{frame}}, $FRAME;
            push @{$DETAILS{slot}}, $1;
            push @{$DETAILS{part_no}},  $2;
            push @{$DETAILS{serial_no}},  $3;
            push @{$DETAILS{board_name}},  $4;
        }
    }
    ## And the rest of the script follows the same format
```

In my perl script, my logic is if the line/word/header(as I prefer to call it) is found, assign a variable with a true or `1`. Then in another `if` statement if the variable is `1`, search for the data needed using regex and store it in a hash.

Now my main problem is that it is not dynamic. If you noticed I did an `if` statement for every header and the variable that is used to store a `1` is different for every header; if it's `Catalyst tester` then the variable would be `$FOUND_CAT = 1;`.

Somethings to take note of: for the header specifically `CATALYST_TH 1`, there will always be  `BACKPLANE A` or it could be `BACKPLANE B`. If there is a `BACKPLANE B` I would have to write another if statement and push everything into the hash again. It's tedious because other log files may have even up to C or D which I do not know of yet, therefore making my script hard to maintain.

Other headers only need one line like `PRECISION_AC 1`. Only `CATALYST_TH 1` will always have a backplane. This is just to take note in case it affects any answers.

So any help on this? Is there anyway to reduce the number of variables? Or even the number or if statements? I've tried but that way it wouldn't push other data into the hash if it's not true. Suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

P.S. Ignore the comments with one '#' symbol, those are part of the log file. The ones with two '#' symbols, like '##' are the comments I have added in.

Answer (score 1):

Since your parsing has lots of state in it depending on what your program has already seen I would switch from regex to [Parse-RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-RecDescent/lib/Parse/RecDescent.pm), which can easily handle all that state nicely.

It's a steep learning curve at first though. There's a tutorial on it [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JTBRAUN/Parse-RecDescent-1.967009/tutorial/tutorial.html), and an older, simpler tutorial [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/06/13/recdecent.html).